# Hammer for Mac constantly rebuilding

Tags: macos, hammerformac

When using Hammer for Mac (http://hammerformac.com, v1.6.12), after saving a file, the app will rebuild the entire project.

However, it has started to rebuild constantly without stopping. It doesn't actually rebuild a project because it is cycling through its rebuild cycle over and over. Only if I manually click "Rebuild Now" does it stop the cycle and actually rebuild and stop.

Anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have described all this time ago, is similar to an issue we're seeing now on the El Capitan pre-release. It's related to FSEvents and the way messages are sent about changes to the file system. It's something we've seen sporadically in the past, but we're working on a fix for the latest issue in preparation for El Capitan public release.

Disclaimer: I'm the new owner and developer of Hammerformac

Best
Steve

Comment: As a follow up, you can download the new non-Mac App Store version (6.8)  from http://hammerformac.com which resolves this issue.